# Multiple Checkboxes, Only One Is Selectable

Tags: html, css, forms, checkbox, label

So I have these checkboxes on a page, but no matter which one I click on, only the first one gets the check mark. I have no idea what the problem is. At first I was having the problem that the checkbox wouldn't show up as checked, but now it's just the first one that is getting selected. There is a button on the page that selects all the boxes, and that works, it is just when a user tries to select one that it does't work.

Code

```
.checkbox {
        margin: 3px auto;
        width: 25px;
        position: relative;
}
.checklabel {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        width: 25px;
        height: 25px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: #eee;
        border:1px solid #ddd;
}
.checkbox .checklabel:after {
        opacity: 0.2;
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 9px;
        height: 5px;
        background: transparent;
        top: 6px;
        left: 7px;
        border: 3px solid #333;
        border-top: none;
        border-right: none;

        transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.checklabel:hover::after {
        opacity: .5;
}
.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checklabel:after {
        opacity: 1;
}



<td><div class="checkbox"><input class="check" id="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label></div></td>
<td><div class="checkbox"><input class="check" id="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label></div></td>
```

Comment: don't re use IDs.

Comment: It's because they both have the same ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [`id` may only be used once per page](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute), and the `for` attribute of your label needs to reference the unique `id` for the input you want it to control.

```css
.checkbox {
  margin: 3px auto;
  width: 25px;
  position: relative;
}

.checklabel {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.checkbox .checklabel:after {
  opacity: 0.2;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 9px;
  height: 5px;
  background: transparent;
  top: 6px;
  left: 7px;
  border: 3px solid #333;
  border-top: none;
  border-right: none;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.checklabel:hover::after {
  opacity: .5;
}

.checkbox input[type=checkbox]:checked + .checklabel:after {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div class="checkbox"><input class="check" id="check" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check"></label></div>
</td>

<td>
  <div class="checkbox"><input class="check" id="check2" type="checkbox"><label class="checklabel" for="check2"></label></div>
</td>
```